# Regex - how to exclude single word?

Tags: regex

I am using http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/ for validation. Validation rules are defined in a following way:

```
            "onlyLetterSp": {
                "regex": /^[a-zA-Z\ \']+$/,
                "alertText": "* Only letters"
            }
```

I would like to add new rule, which will exclude one single word. I have read some similar questions on StackOverflow and tried to declare it with something like this

```
"regex": /(?!exclude_word)\^[a-zA-Z\ \']+$/,
```

But it didn't work. Can you give me some advices how to do it?

Comment: maybe you should live out ^? Like this /(?!exclude_word)[a-zA-Z\ \']+$/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
\b(?:(?!word)\w)+\b
```

Will not match the "word".

Comment: Pretty close, but I'm pretty sure it will reject any word with the word `word` in it as well like `wordy` or `wordsmith`

Comment: @CodeJockey I agree. OP should instead accept your answer. Did that in a hurry while working so I didn't thoroughly test it.

Comment: Well then, perhaps @mkas will return at some point and revisit the selection? :D thanks, by the way!

Comment: @FailedDev - hey, if you still think the OP should have accpeted my answer, you could point to or copy my answer or update yours for the benefit of those visitors that aren't very good with the scroll wheel? :-D

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. If anyone wonders, you can exclude multiple words by separating with | (ie. word|anotherword|etc )

Comment: How do I do this with a list of words that I dont wnat to match?

Answer (score 46):

This is a good time to use word boundary assertions, like @FailedDev indicated, but care needs to be exercised to avoid rejecting certain not-TOO-special cases, such as `wordy`, `wordsmith` or even not so obviously cases like `sword` or `foreword`

I believe this will work pretty well:

```regex
\b(?!\bword\b)\w+\b
```

This is the expression broken down:

```regex
\b        # assert at a word boundary
(?!       # look ahead and assert that what follows IS NOT... 
  \b      #   a word boundary
  word    #   followed by the exact characters `word`
  \b      #   followed by a word boundary
)         # end look-ahead assertion
\w+       # match one or more word characters: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
\b        # then a word boundary
```

The expression in the original question, however, matches more than word characters. `[a-zA-Z\ \']+` matches spaces (to support multiple words in the input) and single quotes as well (for apostrophes?). If you need to allow words with apostrophes in them then use the following expression:

```regex
\b(?!\bword\b)[a-zA-Z']+\b
```

[image: RegexBuddy test to exclude a 'word' from matching]

Answer (score 7):

It's unclear from your question what you want, but I've interpreted it as "not matching input that contains a particular word". The regex for this is:

```
^(?!.*\bexclude_word\b)
```