# Exclude exact string using regex negative lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to exclude `pqr` from a string using regex.

What I currently have is

```
abc\/(?!.*pqr).*\/xyz
```

This correctly rejects `abc/pqr/xyz`, but it also rejects `abc/pqrst/xyz` which I want it to match.

I want `pqr` only to be excluded when it's a complete word, and not when it's a sub-string of a longer word such as `pqrst`.

Comment: A whole word `pqr`? Add `\b` around. `abc\/(?!.*\bpqr\b).*\/xyz`. See https://regex101.com/r/HjJBBH/1

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Its working now :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex - how to exclude single word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820930/regex-how-to-exclude-single-word)

Comment: Other comments under your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [**word boundaries**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) with `pqr` that is inside the lookahead:

```
 abc\/(?!.*\bpqr\b).*\/xyz
           ^^   ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HjJBBH/1).  If you do not use word boundaries, any `pqr` will cause the regex to fail, ans when you add the word boundaries, only those matches will be failed where `pqr` is present as a whole word.

An alternative is to match `pqr` in specific context:

```
 abc\/(?!(?:.*\/)?pqr\/).*\/xyz
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/HjJBBH/2). Here, `(?!(?:.*\/)?pqr\/)` will match after `abc/` or after `abc` followed with 0+ any chars up to the last `/` and only when followed with another `/`. In all other contexts, you will have a match.

NOTE: Same approaches should be applied to `xyz` (you may add a `\b` after it to match a whole word `xyz`.

NOTE2: To require `pqr` to appear before `xyz`, use `abc\/(?!(?:(?!\/xyz).)*\bpqr\b).*\/xyz`.

Comment: You close questions as a duplicate often. Why did you answer this one that has been asked billions of times before?

Comment: Because a word boundary is not the only solution here. The question is not really about a word boundary. Read carefully before blaming. Also, there is much more to say here than "use `\b`".

Comment: Given that the regex uses `.*` rather than `\w*`, isn't there a chance that a valid value starts with `pqr` followed by something in `\W`?

Comment: @Rawling: That is why I suggest an alternative approach. It might be further improved - `abc\/(?!(?:.*\/)?pqr(?:\/|$)).*\/xyz` (to allow matching `pqr` at the end of the string).

Comment: Comments here are for discussion about the answer - not for discussion about question closures etc... If you really want to - take it to [meta]

Answer (score 0):

A simple check would be just to see that you don't have `pqr/` at that point:

```
abc\/(?!.*pqr\/).*\/xyz
```

Also note the `.*` in `(?!.*` stops you from accepting `abc/defpqr/xyz`; are you sure that is what you want?